# PyGithub - Cant import Github from github

Tags: python, pygithub

I am working on a project that needs to interface with github and clone the repo as a way to update itself.

I am just beginning to play around with PyGithub (seems very easy to use) but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\joey\Desktop\TEST\cloning.py", line 2, in <module>
    from github import GitHub
ImportError: cannot import name 'GitHub' from 'github' (C:\Users\joey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\github\__init__.py)
```

Things I have already tried:

installing to the path with

```
pip install --target=C:\Users\joeya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages pygithub
```

I tried `python -m pip install pygithub`

I followed almost everything I could after googling my error code and yet still I am not able to run this example from the documentation:

```
from github import GitHub

def main():
    g = GitHub('MY TOKEN')
    for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
        print(repo.name)
        repo.edit(has_wiki=False)
    # to see all the available attributes and methods
    print(dir(repo))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am sure it is a simple fix but I have run out of ideas.
python -V - Python 3.9.5
pip -V - pip 21.2.1

Comment: error shows you path to source code - so open this file and see if it has `GitHub`. Maybe you installed wrong module. Or maybe it uses different name - ie. lowercase `github`

Comment: or maybe it needs program `git` to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be `Github` with lowercase `h`.

You can see it even in examples in [documentation](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) or on [PyPi.org](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/)

Comment: OH... MY... GOD... i knew it would be something simple and I swear I looked at that. This is what I get for not just copy pasting the example lol. Thanks man

Comment: I never used this module but If I would have to write this code then I would automatically use `GitHub`. Frankly I should write this explanation as comment because it is only small typo.

Comment: I was getting the same kind of error but this time using the correct name, with a lowercase `h`:   (1) `from github import Github` (2) `ImportError: cannot import name 'Github' from 'github' (c:\dropboxs\abu\Dropbox\python\github.py)`    (3) Solution: don't call your own script `github.py` to avoid conflicts with PyGithub library files https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/472#issuecomment-253235836

Comment: @abu it is common problem when beginners start use some module - they use the same name for script. ie. someone learn to create game using module `pygame` and he puts code in script `pygame.py`, etc.